# Can I Intercept NextJs Compile Step?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have some React developer experience/productivity improvement ideas that depend on static analysis of component files. I'd like to run some script to generate some code in component files if some characters appear in said files.

[image]

NextJS automatically runs its compiler whenever a component file changes, so I'd like to intercept/hook into that compile step to run my script and generate some code before the compiler continues.

I've looked around, but I can't find anything that suggests a way to go about doing this.

Comment: Have you considered using `nodemon`? https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/791  I am not sure if this fits your use case though. Maybe sharing a bit more info about the code you want to generate will help folks here be able to offer better suggestions.

Comment: We already use nodemon, but that's only useful for serverside changes. NextJS compiles only on frontend file changes, and we wouldn't want to change this as it'd be unbearably slow.

Answer (score 0):

`next/build` does not expose hooks, so you cannot get in *front* of it like you are asking. You can use `nodemon` or something similar to listen to `.next/server/pages/**` and do something *after* the build script, or listen to `src/pages/**` and do something *at the same time* as the dev rebuild, but you cannot get in front of it.

This is actually a pretty common feature for other bundlers (Rollup etc.), so I opened a [feature request](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/39540) for you.

Comment: Thanks for opening that feature request. Nodemon isn't much of an option since we don't want to cause our server to restart as a result of this. I want to tap into the NextJS compile step because that's run when frontend (React) files change, which nodemon is not (and should not). Please let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: @lwdthe1 Nodemon will watch your source files, like `src/pages/index.tsx`, and do something when one of them changes. It runs in a terminal like `next dev`. It would not cause Next to rebuild the page unless it changed one of those files, which Next is also watching. What specifically do you want to do when Next rebuilds?

Comment: Nodemon restarts the server when the files that it watches change. When that server restarts, we have to wait for it before our app can be reloaded or to interact with the server because we serve our app via a custom nose server. When the server eventually restarts, the app will do a hard reload. None of that is desirable.  I just want to generate code that normalizes any of our source files that were changed with needed resources and any necessary syntax updates. I want that to be picked up by NextJs's compiler to be represented after hot module reload.